# Necessity and sufficiency table

Tags: logic

Is the table below correct according to the traditional understanding?

[image]

**Corrected table:**
[image]

References:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sufficient.html, http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Necessary.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  If the condition can be true and the result false, the condition is not sufficient.  If the condition can be false and the result true, the condition is not necessary.

EDIT:  The revised tables are correct, if interpreted in the following sense.
Both $C$ and $R$ generally have free variables, so you don't generally assign them truth values as such.
Condition $C$ is sufficient for result $R$ if whenever you assign values to the free variables, the corresponding truth values for $(C,R)$ are never $(T,F)$;  $(T,T)$, $(F, T)$, and $(F,F)$ are allowed.
Similarly, 
condition $C$ is necessary for result $R$ if whenever you assign values to the free variables, the corresponding truth values for $(C,R)$ are never $(F,T)$; $(T,T)$, $(T, F)$, and $(F,F)$ are allowed.